# Binomial theorem to find $n$

Tags: binomial-theorem

If the coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion $(3x^2-2/x)^n$ is $-54$, find the value of $n$.

When I tried to do it using the normal expansion $nCr$, I ended up with 2 simultaneous equations (A&B) which cannot be solved.

$2n=3r$----A
$\qquad nCr*3^{(n+1-r)}*(-2)^{(r-1)}=-54$ ----B

Please help :)

Comment: The formatting of the question is not the best. And try $n=3$.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your math text. This link may be a useful reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If someone can give me method that can be used in general ?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
Using the Binomial Theorem, you should get
$$
(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}
$$
In your case, $a = 3x^2$ and $b = -2/x$. Can you

1. plug in and simplify the terms
2. find the term with $x^3$ -- what value(s) of $k$ would it correspond to?
3. compute its coefficient?

Answer (score 1):

Using the *binomial formula*:
$$\Bigl(3x^2-\frac2x\Bigr)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n-r}\binom nr 3^rx^{2r} \frac{2^{n-r}}{x^{n-r}}=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n-r}\binom nr 3^r2^{n-r} x^{3r-n}$$
This formula shows the coefficient of $x^3$ is $-54$ if and only if
$$(\mathrm i)\;3r-n=3,\qquad (\mathrm{ii})\;n-r \text{ is odd },\qquad (\mathrm{iii})\;\binom nr 3^r2^{n-r}=54=2\cdot 3^3 $$
Equation (iii) shows $\dbinom nr2^{n-r}$ has $2$-valuation equal to $1$, hence $n-r\le 1$. Observe $n-r$ can't be $0$ since then $\dbinom nr=1$ and the l.h.s. of (iii) is equal to $3^r$. So, necessarily $n-r=1$, i.e. $r=n-1$, and eq. (i)  becomes
$$3(n-1)-n=3\iff 2n=6.$$
Thus we have $n=3,\;r=2$ (note condition (ii) is satisfied).